# Angular 1.5 and new Component Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router

I'm using angular 1.5 beta 2 and the new router from Angular 2 alpha 45.
I couldn't find examples of usage for the latest router with Angular 1.
I can find examples of the usage of the router for Angular 2, using `@RouteConfig`.

Can someone explain how I would configure an angular 1 controller? And, if possible, a full working example?

Answer (score 14):

**Update** They have stopped working on this version of the Router and started a version 3 with different APIs. [As of June 20, 2016 there was no recommended way](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12926#issuecomment-227114911) for using the router v3 with Angular 1. I'm not sure if this has changed since. This question and answer below relates to Router v2 (aka ComponentRouter).

---

**Obsolete API**
A few sites indicate that a component in Angular 1 (for the purpose of the new router) is a controller registered as `[name]Controller` and a template picked up from `component/[name]/[name].html`. This is now obsolete.

**New API**
This [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12926) contains recent information, explaining how to get the latest Angular 1 new router version.

The component used in the configuration is mapped to a directive registered with the component name. See this [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/MxzjC99l8WDbuEu14ws2?p=preview).

```
angular.module('app.home', [])
.directive('home', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Hello {{ home.text }}',
    controller: function HomeController() {
      this.text = 'World';
    },
    controllerAs: 'home'
  }
});
```

With Angular 1.5 there is a new syntax for registering components, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12933). I've used it with this syntax:

```
angular.module('app.home', [])
.component('home', {
  restrict: "EA",
  template: 'Hello {{ home.text }}',
  controller: function HomeController() {
    this.text = 'World';
  }
  // to configure a child route
  //,$routeConfig: [
  //  { aux: "/son", component: "son", as: "Left" },
  //  { aux: "/daughter", component: "daughter", as: "Left" }]
});
```

Comment: Found another sample at https://github.com/brandonroberts/angularjs-component-router

Comment: I couldn't set up child routes correctly, and couldn't find a working sample with child routes

Comment: The discussion on the angular github led to this demo with a child route http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZNQzWfspvpmMCLRBOdN?p=preview

Comment: Works great! I have two additional request. Could you add information about how to use it with route parameters? And also, how to use it with the component helper method you mentioned which is now available in the 1.5 rc.

Comment: I added the 1.5 component usage, regarding the parameters can you open a new question and link it here?

Comment: You would add $router to the controller correct?  Or is there another way to access $routeConfig?

Comment: @stevek in the code example `$routeConfig` is just a field name on the object, no need to inject anything at that point.

Comment: Is there any update regarding the new router? 1.5 version was released without the new router.
What is the best example to use the router?

Answer (score 4):

Although it is pretty new at this point you can also use a root component with the new angular router.  This component could take additional components as children.

I followed Pete Bacon Darwin's example to get a version going. 
https://github.com/petebacondarwin/ng1-component-router-demo

Notice in his version The main component has $router.config passed in the run block and identifies children with 3 dots.

```
.run(function($router) {
    $router.config([
    { path: '/...', name: 'App', component: 'app', useAsDefault: true }
    ]);
```

I am using angular 1.5.0  to follow his github.  I ran into issues playing with release some of the release candidates.

Comment: I found this on 0.1.  I believe they are releasing 0.3.